# Test whether a dataframe is a sorted version of another dataframe

Tags: r, sorting, comparison, dataframe

Is it feasible to test whether some dataframe is simply a sorted version of another dataframe? For example, if I have two dataframes `a` and `b`, is there some way to easily determine whether `a` is simply a reordered version of `b` (or vice versa)?

Here's a trivial example:

```
a <- data.frame(x1=1:10, x2=11:20, x3=1:2)
b <- a[order(a$x3, a$x1, decreasing=TRUE),]
```

The closest thing I can think of is `all.equal`, but its output is not helpful (to me, at least):

```
> all.equal(a,b)
[1] "Attributes: < Component 2: Mean relative difference: 0.9545455 >"
[2] "Component 1: Mean relative difference: 0.9545455"                
[3] "Component 2: Mean relative difference: 0.3387097"                
[4] "Component 3: Mean relative difference: 0.6666667"
```

I imagine there is some obvious way to do this that is alluding me. I'm looking for a general solution that would scale well to many variables and many observations (thus the above example is simply for demonstration).

Also: Ideally, such a function would also identify whether `a` is a subset of `b` (or vice versa).

Comment: My first instinct is also to use `order` and `identical`, though it seems you are more interested in the general scenario of testing subsets. Here's a not-very-popular but potentially helpful question from a few years ago in which users discuss hashing and joining: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086794/create-hash-value-for-each-row-of-data-in-dataframe-in-r

Comment: @Peyton That's interesting. I had sort of considered hashing, but hadn't thought it through completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would explore the "compare" package:

```
library(compare)
compare(a, b, allowAll=TRUE)
# TRUE
#   sorted
```

Here, it shows that it had to sort the data before it found the data to be the same.

Here's a slightly more complicated example, with factors coerced to character, rows reordered, and columns reordered:

```
a <- data.frame(x1=1:10, x2=11:20, x3=1:2, x4 = letters[1:10])
b <- with(a, a[order(x3, x1, decreasing=TRUE), ])
b$x4 <- as.character(b$x4)
b <- b[c(4, 1, 3, 2)]
```

Here's the result of `compare`:

```
compare(a, b, allowAll=TRUE)
# TRUE
#   reordered columns
#   [x4] coerced from <character> to <factor>
#   sorted
```

Comment: @Thomas, perhaps `merge` in combination with this package would help you devise a more comprehensive answer to your full question.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort both data frames along all columns and use `identical`:

```
identical(a[do.call(order, a), ], b[do.call(order, b), ])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You'd have to sort on all columns in order to break ties.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the data.frames together and return everything that is not duplicated. If that statement is empty they are likely the same.

```r
a <- data.frame(x1 = 1:10, x2 = 11:20, x3 = 1:2)
b <- a[order(a$x3, a$x1, decreasing = TRUE), ]
rbind(a, b)[which(!(duplicated(rbind(a, b)) | duplicated(rbind(a, b),
                                                         fromLast = TRUE))), ]
# [1] x1 x2 x3
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I find the statement useful to find out which rows *are* different. This is especially true when looking at very large tables with very few differences for which the output of `all.equal()` is not useful IMHO.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID =  rep("007", 6),
                  fruit = c("apple", "mango", "orange", NA, "kiwi", "banana"),
                  seq = 1:6)

df2 <- data.frame(ID =  rep("007", 6),
                  fruit = c("apple", "mango", "kiwi", "orange", NA, "banana"),
                  seq = 1:6)

all.equal(df1, df2)
# [1] "Component “fruit”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 1 in current 1 in target"

rbind(df1, df2)[which(!(duplicated(rbind(df1, df2)) | duplicated(rbind(df1, df2),
                                                                 fromLast = TRUE))), ]

#     ID  fruit seq
# 3  007 orange   3
# 4  007   <NA>   4
# 5  007   kiwi   5
# 9  007   kiwi   3
# 10 007 orange   4
# 11 007   <NA>   5
```

I would have preferred to answer this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706019/checking-if-one-data-frame-is-a-reorder-of-another-data-frame) but that thread was closed with a reference to this thread.