# Create hash value for each row of data with selected columns in dataframe in python pandas

Tags: python, hash, pandas

I have asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086794/create-hash-value-for-each-row-of-data-in-dataframe-in-r) in R about creating hash value for each row of data. I know that I can use something like `hashlib.md5(b'Hello World').hexdigest()` to hash a string, but how about a row in a dataframe?

#### update 01

I have drafted my code as below:

```
for index, row in course_staff_df.iterrows():
        temp_df.loc[index,'hash'] = hashlib.md5(str(row[['cola','colb']].values)).hexdigest()
```

It seems not very pythonic to me, any better solution?

Answer (score 19):

Or simply:

```
df.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis = 1)
```

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,5))
print df
df.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis = 1)

     0         1         2         3         4
0  0.728046  0.542013  0.672425  0.374253  0.718211
1  0.875581  0.512513  0.826147  0.748880  0.835621
2  0.451142  0.178005  0.002384  0.060760  0.098650

0    5024405147753823273
1    -798936807792898628
2   -8745618293760919309
```

Comment: For all future readers just be warned that using `int64` for later hash comparison in pandas might not be the best idea as column datatypes in pandas get messed around with a lot. Instead of comparing `int64` you accidentally might compare to type `obj` or even `float` which then results in false negatives. Might be better to use `df["rowhash"] = df.apply(lambda x: hashlib.md5(str(tuple(x)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), axis = 1)`. Note: `tuple` speeds up the function.

Comment: Moreover, built-in hash() function is not deterministic and depends on PYTHONHASHSEED, which takes a random value for each process when not set

Answer (score 15):

This is now available in [`pandas.util.hash_pandas_object`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html):

```
pandas.util.hash_pandas_object(df)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "Create hash value for each row of data with selected columns in DataFrame in Python Pandas" - a row is not semantically a Pandas object in the first place - the docs say the function you gave: "Return a data hash of the Index/Series/DataFrame" - none of these are "rows"

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is not great.

Comment: Please do note that while the documentation is not great, for data frames, it will hash each column element-by-element, and then combine those hashes element-wise, resulting in one hash per row - see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f538741432edf55c6b9fb5d0d496d2dd1d7c2457/pandas/core/util/hashing.py#L174 - it is done this way for performance reasons, where access patterns by column are typically faster.

Answer (score 12):

> Create hash value for each row of data with selected columns in dataframe in python pandas

These solutions work for the life of the Python process.

If order matters, one method would be to coerce the row (a Series object) to a tuple:

```
>>> hash(tuple(df.irow(1)))
-4901655572611365671
```

This demonstrates order matters for tuple hashing:

```
>>> hash((1,2,3))
2528502973977326415
>>> hash((3,2,1))
5050909583595644743
```

To do so for every row, appended as a column would look like this:

```
>>> df = df.drop('hash', 1) # lose the old hash
>>> df['hash'] = pd.Series((hash(tuple(row)) for _, row in df.iterrows()))
>>> df
           y  x0                 hash
0  11.624345  10 -7519341396217622291
1  10.388244  11 -6224388738743104050
2  11.471828  12 -4278475798199948732
3  11.927031  13 -1086800262788974363
4  14.865408  14  4065918964297112768
5  12.698461  15  8870116070367064431
6  17.744812  16 -2001582243795030948
7  16.238793  17  4683560048732242225
8  18.319039  18 -4288960467160144170
9  18.750630  19  7149535252257157079

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

If order does not matter, use the hash of frozensets instead of tuples:

```
>>> hash(frozenset((3,2,1)))
-272375401224217160
>>> hash(frozenset((1,2,3)))
-272375401224217160
```

Avoid summing the hashes of all of the elements in the row, as this could be cryptographically insecure and lead to hashes that fall outside the range of the original.

(You could use modulo to constrain the range, but this amounts to rolling your own hash function, and the best practice is *not* to.)

You can make permanent cryptographic quality hashes, for example using sha256, as well using [the `hashlib` module.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)

There is some discussion of the API for cryptographic hash functions in [PEP 452](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0452/).

Thanks to users Jamie Marshal and Discrete Lizard for their comments.

Answer (score 1):

I've came up with this adaption from the code provided on the question:

```
new_df2 = df.copy()
key_combination = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
new_df2.index = list(map(lambda x: hashlib.sha1('-'.join([col_value for col_value in x]).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), new_df2[key_combination].values))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df.set_index(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df), drop=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.