# How can I create a unique ID for Pandas DataFrame before I push this to Google BigQuery using to_gbq or to_sql?

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

Need to add a unique ID to the dataframe and push to BigQuery(Since BigQuery does not support auto-increment values)

Comment: Check out python built-in [hash](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=hash#hash) command

Comment: Similarly, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757042/create-hash-value-for-each-row-of-data-with-selected-columns-in-dataframe-in-pyt

Comment: @Ranjith could you please, let us know if the link provided by rtenha is sufficient for your needs?