# Pandas `hash_pandas_object` not producing duplicate hash values for duplicate entires

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hash

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, and I know that `df2` is a subset of `df1`. What I am trying to do is find the set difference between `df1` and `df2`, such that `df1` has only entries that are different from those in `df2`. To accomplish this, I first used `pandas.util.hash_pandas_object` on each of the dataframes, and then found the set difference between the two hashed columns.

```
df1['hash'] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df1, index=False)
df2['hash'] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df2, index=False)
df1 = df1.loc[~df1['hash'].isin(df2['hash'])]
```

This results in `df1` remaining the same size; that is, none of the hash values matched. However, when I use a `lambda` function, `df1` is reduced by the expected amount.

```
df1['hash'] = df1.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
df2['hash'] = df2.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
df1 = df1.loc[~df1['hash'].isin(df2['hash'])]
```

The problem with the second approach is that it takes an extremely long time to execute (`df1` has about 3 million rows). Am I just misunderstanding how to use `pandas.util.hash_pandas_object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case you are hashing the complete dataframe, while in the second case you are hashing each individual row.

If your objective is to remove the duplicate rows, you can achieve it faster using left/right merge with `indicator` option and then drop the rows that are not unique to the original dataframe.

```py
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=list_columns, indicator=True)
df_merged = df_merged[df_merged.indicator=="left_only"] # this will keep only unmatched rows
```

Comment: Another SO question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757042/create-hash-value-for-each-row-of-data-with-selected-columns-in-dataframe-in-pyt) mentioned `hash_pandas_object` in response to hashing each row, so I assumed it would do this. If not, what does it do exactly. I should've mentioned that I tried the `merge` method as well, but I'm getting a ValueError: `You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`. I can't figure out that error for my data.

Comment: The comments in that answer make it clear that the most popular answer hashes the complete object rather than every row. The error you have indicates that there's a mismatch in dtype, so that best fixed by specifying relevant dtype, e.g. `df.astype({'some_string_col': 'string', 'some_num_col': 'float', # etc})`.

Comment: Just to complete this answer, my dataframes were taken from very similar datasets, but for some reason, the datatypes were not matching, so I first changed the datatypes for `df2` to those of `df1`: `df2 = df2.astype(df1.dtypes)`. Then I could merge (`merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True)`), and select the rows only in `df1` as @SultanOrazbayev suggested.